# set conditions while uploading from csv file

Tags: php, mysql

so, I have this users list which I get it from a csv file.

What I need to do is this:
I get the file to upload, I check for each line if the user exists, if he does then all I do is update him, if he doesn't I should create a new account for him.

I do know how to do it as a logic... but I become confused while using the csv import...

So, here it is what I use:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into users (Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id,age,sex) values('$data[0]','".md5($data[1])."','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);
```

What I need is something like this:

```
foreach (user as $data[7]) {
    if user exists in user table then $query1 
    else $query2    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have wrote the logic in pseudo code. Lookup `SELECT` to check if an user exists. Then just write the two queries.

Comment: could you please help me with something visual?
because i know i wrot eit in pseudocode, but i don't know the syntax, starting from the part in foreach section...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @AlbM - You managed to write the `insert` statement. I therefore inferred you know a little about SQL. So why not go the extra mile with `select`?

Comment: Yes Ed.. i mean, i could do that.. i am more worried about the syntax at the foreach part, if i should do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a handy little function called `LOAD DATA INFILE`, which allows it to load CSV files directly, without you needing to do the insert loop in PHP.

You entire code could be as simple as this:

```
$import="LOAD DATA INFILE '{$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']}' INTO users (Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id,age,sex)";
mysqli_query($connection, $import) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

See the MySQL manual page here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

note: I haven't tested the above. If MySQL doesn't have direct read access to the temp file, you may need to move it to a location the MySQL can read first, or use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead.

note2: I'm using `mysqli_xxx()` functions instead of `mysql_xx()` because the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated. Feel free to change it back if you need to, but be aware that `mysql_xx()` is not recommended for use. I suggest you change all your `mysql_xx()` calls to `mysqli_xxx()` as soon as convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If `user_id` is primary key of your table you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to insert new row or update existing ones in just one statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (Username,Password,Email,first_name,last_name,phone,user_id,age,sex)  
VALUES('$data[0]','".md5($data[1])."','$data[2]','$data[3]',
       '$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        Username = '$data[0]', 
        Password = '".md5($data[1])."', 
        Email = '$data[2]', 
        first_name = '$data[3]', 
        last_name = '$data[4]', 
        phone = '$data[5]', 
        age = '$data[7]', 
        sex = '$data[8]';
```

Check details in MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html